How do I get the destination chains which have been executed based on the input
Output which I get from the bellow code :
{'input': '2+2', 'text': 'Sure, I'd be happy to help with that question!\n\nThe question you've asked is "2 + 2."\n\nTo answer this question, we can follow the order of operations, which is often remembered by the acronym PEMDAS: Parentheses, Exponents, Multiplication and Division (from left to right), Addition and Subtraction (from left to right).\n\nIn this case, we are just adding two numbers together, so we don't need to worry about the order of operations. We can simply add 2 + 2 to get:\n\n2 + 2 = 4\n\nSo, the answer to the question "2 + 2" is 4. Let me know if you have any other questions!'}
Expected :
math
In the above, I just need the chain as output which have been executed.
from langchain.utilities import SQLDatabase
from langchain.agents import create_sql_agent
from langchain.agents.agent_toolkits import SQLDatabaseToolkit
from langchain.agents.agent_types import AgentType
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.prompts.chat import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain.chains.router import MultiPromptChain
from langchain.chains.router.llm_router import LLMRouterChain, RouterOutputParser
from google.colab import userdata
from langchain_groq import ChatGroq
GROQ=userdata.get('GROQ')


# Initialize the ChatGroq language model
llm = ChatGroq(temperature=0.1,
                groq_api_key=GROQ,
                model_name="mixtral-8x7b-32768",
                max_tokens=32000,
                top_p=0.1,
                frequency_penalty=0.1,
                presence_penalty=0.1)

# Define prompt templates for different subjects
physics_template = """You are a very smart physics professor. \
You are great at answering questions about physics in a concise\
and easy to understand manner. \
When you don't know the answer to a question you admit\
that you don't know.

Here is a question:
{input}"""

math_template = """You are a very good mathematician. \
You are great at answering math questions. \
You are so good because you are able to break down \
hard problems into their component parts,
answer the component parts, and then put them together\
to answer the broader question.

Here is a question:
{input}"""

history_template = """You are a very good historian. \
You have an excellent knowledge of and understanding of people,\
events and contexts from a range of historical periods. \
You have the ability to think, reflect, debate, discuss and \
evaluate the past. You have a respect for historical evidence\
and the ability to make use of it to support your explanations \
and judgements.

Here is a question:
{input}"""


# Defining the prompt templates
prompt_infos = [
    {
        "name": "physics",
        "description": "Good for answering questions about physics",
        "prompt_template": physics_template
    },
    {
        "name": "math",
        "description": "Good for answering math questions",
        "prompt_template": math_template
    },
    {
        "name": "History",
        "description": "Good for answering history questions",
        "prompt_template": history_template
    }
]

destination_chains = {}
for p_info in prompt_infos:
    name = p_info["name"]
    prompt_template = p_info["prompt_template"]
    prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template=prompt_template)
    chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt)
    destination_chains[name] = chain

destinations = [f"{p['name']}: {p['description']}" for p in prompt_infos]
destinations_str = "\n".join(destinations)


default_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template("{input}")
default_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=default_prompt)


router_template = MULTI_PROMPT_ROUTER_TEMPLATE.format(
    destinations=destinations_str
)
router_prompt = PromptTemplate(
    template=router_template,
    input_variables=["input"],
    output_parser=RouterOutputParser(),
)

router_chain = LLMRouterChain.from_llm(llm, router_prompt)


chain = MultiPromptChain(router_chain=router_chain,
                         destination_chains=destination_chains,
                         default_chain=default_chain, verbose=True
                        )


